# Use Eduroam to connect to PEAP and MSCHAPv2

Tags: wireless

I'm been using Eduroam on my Ubuntu-client for the last three years now, and with every new version, there is harder and harder to connect to Eduroam (my university network).

Up until now it has worked with just using PEAP and MSCHAPv2, with my university credentials. this time though after endless hours, it's still not willing to connect. Anyone got an idea on how, or even managed to do it them self? Eduroam is on just about all universities in the world, so i guess I'm not the only Ubuntu-user needing this?

Comment: can you explain the steps you take (with images or so)? (I expect it should be: edit wireless, set inner auth to PAP, username, password and no certs BUT it could be diff. per university...).

Comment: Oh! Might we know the univeristy? Long shot but maybe someone is around that knows the setup ;)

Comment: Thanks. Its Norwegian School of Economics.
What I do is: 
1) add WiFi with SSID:eduroam
2) WiFi-security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise 
3) PEAP as authentication and MSCHAPv2 as inner authentication
4) my studentmail as username and password. I can send pictures if you want?

Comment: LOL .... now all webpages with hits return in Norwegian.

Comment: Is there an error message somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 14.04 eduroam connection:

Edit eduroam connections->Wi-Fi Security:

1. Security : WPA&WPA2 Enterprise
2. Authentication : Protected EAP(PEAP)
3. ANonymous ID: username@.....edu
4. CA Certificate: None (and check the box "No certificate required", if any)
5. PEAP Version : automatic
6. Inner Authentication: MSCHAPv2
7. username : username@....edu
8. passwd: ......

Then ignore the certificate warning.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug with Gnome Network Manager that has inexplicably stuck around (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1104476).
In short, after you try and fail to connect to eduroam for the fist time

1. go to the folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and edit the eduroam entry (e.g. open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam
   ```
2. In this file you'll find an entry `system-ca-certs=true` that you need to delete.
3. Save, and try to connect (it will probably fail at first and you'll have to re-enter the password) it should connect successfully after that!

If it still doesn't connect, try "Edit Connections" under the network menu. Find eduroam and in the "Security" tab, input the password. Then connect. It worked for me!

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that removing that line worked. But it took some time before it allowed me to connect the first time. Had to remove the network-input trough terminal before a fifth try worked.... Sucks that eduroam is so messed up...

Comment: thanks @user273659 ... that hint made my day after a few days of struggling w/ eduroam wifi on 14.04 on a Lenovo E531