# Connecting to eduroam

Tags: wireless, network-manager, lenovo

I'm trying to help a friend to connect to eduroam with his laptop (lenovo ideapad 100), on which ubuntu 16.04 is installed.

Using the NetworkManager we selected the following options in "Wi-Fi-Security" (as per our university's instruction):

- WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Protected EAP (PEAP)
- anonymous identity and CA-certificate left blank
- PEAP-Version: Automatic
- MSCHAPv2
- Username and password

Some time after clicking "Connect" a window pops up and asks for the password to be entered, but even after entering the password, no connection is established. There is no error message. The password is definitely correct. It's possible to connect with other wifi-networks without any problems.

I tried following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454511), however there is no line "system-ca-certs=true" in the text file.

Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed eduroam-cat? For me there was a link on my UNI's website. Installing that made the connection possible.

https://cat.eduroam.org/?lang=eng

Comment: While the answer is valid, not all Universities have taken the step to configure their services in CAT +1